# Laravel url with id not creating active class

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

> after getting last url segment i am creating a class active.
>
> last segment id i have in :

```
@php$get=Request::segment(3);@endphp

<a href="{{BASE}}User/li-ac">
<div class="col-md-12"> 
    <div class="col-md-12  {{ collect(request()->segments())->last()=='li-ac' || collect(request()->segments())->last()=='li-de'  ? 'Active' : '' }}">

    </div>
</div>
</a>
```

> i want to add this $get after
>   collect(request()->segments())->last()=='li-de' in if condition to get
>   my Active class.

```
when Url Is:
```

mysite.com/user/li-ac

```
Its working fine

But Url is:

mysite.com/User/li-de/3

Its not showing that class
```

> how can i add the id at the end of the url in if condition for
>   sideactive class..

Comment: i have 1 exp page where the last is : li-ex and after click on detail i am having new url li-d here the last segment is :3  manging both active class from the same link

Answer (score 0):

When you're using `/newdata/li-de/3` URI, the last segment is `3`. So, change the code to:

```
{{ in_array(request()->segments()[1], ['li-ac', 'li-de']) ? 'sideactive' : '' }}
```

Comment: @Shruti what does `{{ dd(request()->segments()[1]) }}` show?

Answer (score 0):

I am done here is the answer:

```
@php
   $get=Request::segment(2);
@endphp

{{ collect(request()->segments())->last()=='li-de' || $get=='li-de' ? 'active' : '' }}
```

Comment: It's absolutely the same logic you've shown in the question and with `request()->segments())->last()` you'll get `3` when you go to `/newdata/li-de/3`. Also, why the class name you originally posted was `sideactive`, then you changed it to `Active` and now it's `active`?